# Prestashop : best way to integrate frontend

Tags: prestashop

I'm starting on prestashop. I currently have the frontend of a site (html/css). What is the best way to integrate it on a prestashop project. Use the basic theme and modify it ? Use a child theme ? Create a new theme ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a child theme is the way to go, this way you can extended only some part of the inherited theme and ensure a "clean" upgrade path of the theme and Prestashop core. See [here](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/themes/reference/template-inheritance/parent-child-feature/) for more details.